# JBoss 4.2.2 - StackOverflowError starting EJB3

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, java-ee-5, jboss-4.2.x

I'm facing the StackOverflowError exception when start my jboss 4.2.2 server clustered with JGroups. 
Anyone got this problem? I can't resolve...

```
    17:44:23,171 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.j2ee:ear=400-AAAAAAAAAAA.ear,jar=AAAAAAAAAAA.jar,name=AaaaaJMXImpl,service=EJB3
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```